# 04 Expedition ac compressor locked up and the engine wont start?

Tags: ford, ac, expedition

04 Expedition w the 5.4 and the ac compressor locked up on me today and, of course the engine wont start. I was wondering if anyone here had this problem and knows the length of the belt needed to bypass the ac compressor?

Answer (score 2):

Fyi, the pulley on the ac compressor can be changed by it self. If the compressor is locked up. Just remove the ac clutch, if stuck to the pully, or just un hook the electrical connector at the compressor. As long as the pulley bearing is good the pully should spin freely.